# LWJGL: Voxels look bad from far away

Tags: java, lwjgl

So, I am making a voxel game in LWJGL just to test my skills. And I noticed that the voxels, when viewed from far away look bad.
[image: Bad looking]
You can't really see it in a picture, but the little gray squares down at the bottom are supposed to be green, but it almost looks like they are z-fighting with the blocks below them, but they aren't even close to overlapping at the top. Here's my source on GitHub:

https://github.com/Codepixl/GLCraft

The Shape that the voxels are is in

https://github.com/Codepixl/GLCraft/blob/master/src/net/codepixl/GLCraft/render/Shape.java

and each block in the chunks are rendered using an OpenGL list. In each class in the 'World' package, there is an initGL and render function. Is there anything I should glEnable to fix this, or is it something wrong with my shape class? It's also worth mentioning my voxels are wider than  they are tall for some reason I can't find.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The rectangular blocks was due to my aspect ratio being calculated with ints, so it was rounding. I still have the z-fighting issue. It only seems to happen with tiles that have blocks next to them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my

```
gluPerspective(67f,(float)Constants.WIDTH/(float)Constants.HEIGHT,0.0001f, 1000f);
```

to

```
gluPerspective(67f,(float)Constants.WIDTH/(float)Constants.HEIGHT,0.1f, 1000f);
```